# Can QEMU run on VMWare or VirtualBox?

Tags: c, linux, x86, qemu

I want to try out [MARRS86](http://marss86.org/~marss86/index.php/Home), which is a cycle accurate simulator for multicore x86 platforms. It uses [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page). So I was wondering if I can use that simulator inside VMWare or VirtualBox. In other words, has anyone tried running QEMU inside VMWare or VirtualBox?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I want to know before trying it.

Comment: Yes, I've done it before, works fine

Answer (score 3):

qemu is just a software like other (as long as your not playing with KVM), you can run it in a simulator without problem.